# Angular formly - Get model from field in wrapper

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-formly

I am creating a wrapper that will display the model value as a normal text on the page. When mouse over is triggerd on this text it will transform into a formly-field, this workes great.
The problem i have is that the normal text wont change when an edit has been made in the field, so how do i get the value of the model from the field if this is possible?

[I made a bin as an example of my problem.](http://jsbin.com/letuhineqi/edit?html,js,output)

the Wrapper:

```
template: [
                '<div ng-hide="to.editorEnabled" >',
                    '<div ng-mouseover="to.editorEnabled=true">',
                        '{{to.label}}</br>',
                        '{{to.value}}',
                    '</div>',
                '</div>',
                '<div ng-show="to.editorEnabled" ng-mouseleave="to.editorEnabled=false">',
                    '<formly-transclude></formly-transclude>',
                '</div>'
           ]
```

Field and model:

```
vm.model = {textField: "Mouse over this field"};


vm.fields = [
  {
    key: 'textField',
    type: 'input',
    templateOptions: {
      label: 'Text Label',
      type: 'text',
      value:vm.model.textField
    }
  }];
```

Comment: It looks like it is working in the 'bin'. When I fill in the form the model text updates in your HTML. Is this what you are expecting as the behavior?

Comment: Partly. I also want the normal text to be the same as the model value. So when the mouse leaves the field the text is the same as the new edited text.

Comment: End result like this: http://imgur.com/wtldtoS

Comment: Haven't used formly  myself but on a quick look at the documentation it seems you need to place a wathcer on your formly form : http://angular-formly.com/#/example/field-options/watchers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was solved using formly watchers.

[Updated bin](http://jsbin.com/woxuqulequ/edit?js,output)

Code with watcher:

```
vm.fields = [
  {
    key: 'textField',
    type: 'input',
    templateOptions: {
      label: 'Text Label',
      type: 'text',
      value:vm.model.textField
    },
    watcher: {
      listener: function(field, newValue, oldValue, scope, stopWatching) {
        if(newValue) {
          field.templateOptions.value = newValue;
        }
      }
    }
  }];
```